# XSLT Normalize namespace prefixes in an unknown context

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to build an XSLT (1.0) that works on an xml body which always contains the same namespaces but the prefixes for these namespaces are completely unknown and variable. The problem I'm having is that this causes 'undeclared prefix' errors when my application applies the stylesheet to the source xml. What's the best strategy to deal with this? If I know the namespace URIs can I simply reassign all prefix usages to a predefined prefix that I associate with that namespace in the XSLT? What would this look like?

Just as an example:
source xml

```
<unknownPrefix:root 
  xmlns:unknownPrefix="knownURI"
  xmlns:unknownPrefix2="knownURI2"
  xmlns:unknownPrefix3="knownURI3"
>
  <unknownPrefix2:node unknownPrefix3:someattribute="example">text</unknownprefix2:node>
</unknownPrefix:root>
```

Comment: The prefixes that the XML uses are of no significance. Your XSLT stylesheet can use its own prefixes - and as long as they are bound to the correct namespace URIs, there is no reason why you should get an error. Please post a [mcve] showing input, your current XSLT and the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<unknownPrefix:root xmlns:unknownPrefix="knownURI" xmlns:unknownPrefix2="knownURI2" xmlns:unknownPrefix3="knownURI3">
    <unknownPrefix2:node unknownPrefix3:someattribute="example">text</unknownPrefix2:node>
</unknownPrefix:root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:myPrefix1="knownURI" 
xmlns:myPrefix2="knownURI2" 
xmlns:myPrefix3="knownURI3"
exclude-result-prefixes="myPrefix1 myPrefix2 myPrefix3">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="myPrefix1:root/myPrefix2:node/@myPrefix3:someattribute"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>example</result>
```